# Panda Standardising with Condition

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I need some help about standardize with condition, how can i standardise a column of data

```
     Score       Rating     Result
1    20          1200      -1.264911064
2    30          1300      -1.264911064
3    40          1200      -0.632455532
4    50          1300      -0.632455532
5    60          1200       0
6    70          1300       0
7    80          1200       0.632455532
8    90          1300       0.632455532
9    100         1200       1.264911064
10   110         1300       1.264911064
```

I am trying to standardise all the scoers that has the same rating, ie standardise all score that has rating 1200 and 1300. 
the scikit-learn. preprocessing.scalar seems to not support this function.

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Comment: Standardised Score 
-1.264911064
-1.264911064
-0.632455532
-0.632455532
0
0
0.632455532
0.632455532
1.264911064
1.264911064

Answer (score 2):

Groupby `Rating`, then for each subgroup you can use transform to calculate the standardized Z score:

```
df['Result'] = df.groupby('Rating').transform(lambda x: (x-x.mean()) / x.std())
```

Which will give you your desired output:

```
   Score  Rating    Result
0     20    1200 -1.264911
1     30    1300 -1.264911
2     40    1200 -0.632456
3     50    1300 -0.632456
4     60    1200  0.000000
5     70    1300  0.000000
6     80    1200  0.632456
7     90    1300  0.632456
8    100    1200  1.264911
9    110    1300  1.264911
```